# Should we have a [warcraft3] tag for modding and the like?

Tags: discussion, tags

It took me some time to gather the information I needed for a certain problem, and so I thought that I would post that here.

To be more specific:  the information pertains to editing Warcraft 3 maps.

Seems to me like would be rather too specific for here, but the [What topics can I ask here?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) indicates otherwise.

I'm not asking whether I should post my Q–and–A:  I'll do that and judge by the reception.
I am asking for a new [warcraft3](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warcraft3) tag; if someone thinks that none should be made, then please explain for posterity.

Comment: Tags cannot just be created on their own. They have to be added to a question. What questions do you think deserve this tag? If there are none currently, you can ask some. Modding is certainly on-topic here, as long they aren't too broad / "how to get started" / opinion-based / whatever other off-topic reason.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to wait for the tag to be created to post your Warcraft 3 modding question - or any other topic.

Once we have a question or a few about that topic, [any user with 300 reputation can add the tag](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) by editing the question to add it.

Our tags are generally descriptive, meaning they're about the kinds of questions we have, rather than prescriptive, about the kinds of questions we're *allowed* to have.

We sometimes confer on Meta to rename/merge/synonym-ize or blacklist tags if we find they're over-broad ("meta-tags"), excessively granular (like tagging each version of a largely consistent line of tools), or leading users astray from constructive Q&A practices. But for the majority, if an established user found it useful enough to add, then it's probably a useful tag, or at least not harmful. ;)